# Azure cloud service deployment issue with pay as you go subscription - cloud services are not available in this subscription

Tags: azure, subscription, azure-cloud-services, azure-deployment

I am having an issue while deploying an Azure web role to a cloud service. It shows me the error

> Cloud services are not available in this subscription.

I am using a pay as you go subscription on Azure. I don't know if there is any limitation with this subscription for cloud service deployment or not.

[image: Error Details].

Comment: Did you try create your cloud services from portal and then, publish to it through VS?

Comment: Yes, I have done the same thing. First create cloud service on azure portal.Then trying to deploy code using VS 2015. This issue is generate when I am deploying code form VS.

Answer (score 10):

Updated version of JerryGoyal's solution.

Cloud Service Management will have to be done using the new [Azure Portal](http://portal.azure.com), because Cloud Service Management in the old portal will be disabled as of 11/15/2017.

- Log into the new [Azure Portal](http://portal.azure.com).
- Go to the [Subscriptions View](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade).
- Set your account as a Co-Admin. [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator).

Comment: This is the reason, just changed my account and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

I think the issue you're running into is that the Cloud Service Publish Wizard in VS only supports subscriptions in which you are an admin or co-admin granted via via the old portal (manage.windowsazure.com).  If you've been given access via RBAC or the new portal, then VS will not see the resources under those subscriptions.

To work around it, you can build the package using msbuild.exe and then upload it via the portal.

That help?

Comment: I have got a solution from Microsoft tech support that work for me.They suggest me to add as coadmin. Once I have added as coadmin .Then it's work for me.

Comment: @bmoore-msft Is there a link to vote for the feature for Cloud Services to follow RBAC?

Comment: I took a look at a couple different groups and didn't find one - you could start one here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170031-sdk-and-tools

Answer (score 4):

> Cloud services are not available in this subscription

The error is caused because the Cloud Services still use the old deployment model that is based on Azure Service Management (ASM).
 To deploy an ASM based component to Azure you need to be ‘co-admin’ for the subscription.

Right now you are ‘Owner’ on the new portal but this role only has impact on the new ARM based resources.

So, just ask your subscription admin to login to the old portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com) and make you co-administrator:

- Login to the old portal
- Click on Settings –> Administrators
- Click on the Add button at the bottom
- Enter the co-admin email address and click on the OK button.

After this reload your Visual Studio and the problem will be solved.